# Maven can't identify the imported packages in Spring boot multi-module project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I created a very simple multi-module spring boot project. created two modules moduA and moduB. moduA as the controller module and moduB as the service module. I added moduB as the dependency of moduA. but when I try to build the project maven can't identify the imported packages from moduB to moduA.

ModuA POM -

[POM of moduA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdUwq.png)

ModuB POM -
[POM of ModuB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOGAH.png)

Error -
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QKIv.png)
kindly please provide me with a solution for this.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. please add the code in yuour question not as links to images of code. You also would need to include the parent, which I suspect has the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` defined.